# Which form caused my exception?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, exception, error-handling

In the `MyApplication_UnhandledException` event , I want to take a screenshot of the form that caused the error.

I have no problem making screen-print of the form.

But how can I find the form that caused the problem (or iterate back to the latest form) ?

Comment: Note that forms are not the only cause of `UnhandledException`. Non UI objects can do.

Comment: Yes this is why I write (or itterate back to the latest form) :)

Comment: I suggest you to just log the stacktrace then analyze the tracktrace, it will hold the name of the class and method which causes the exception. Then if you cross check it with the sceeen shot that'll be helpful. take screenshot only when they're already **aware** of that, even though cover only your window not the enitre screen.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to capture a screenshot of a form in order to debug the cause of an exception, the [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) should give you all that information, and more - you should log that instead.

Comment: I would agree, but maybe he want to capture what the User does in that moment

Comment: @ChristianSauer yeah I sort of re-worded that part. However, there are much better ways of logging user data for the purpose of debugging.

Comment: @ChristianSauer It is not fair to take a screen shot in user's machine without his knowledge. If the user is you then go ahead.

Comment: I want to capture what the user typed in, so I can type it in myself and hopefully "catch" the error.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel my users are all internal - no external users. And all users are informed about this. This is our company computers not private computers.

Comment: @MojoDK you need to be careful with that, as already pointed out it's not a great idea to be doing stuff like that without the users consent (they have may personal information on the screen when you take a screenshot). If you have permission to record the user session data then I would recommend you implement a proper logging framework.

Comment: @james - this is for our intenal CRM system. All users can see all informations, so there's absolutely no private information. My first thought was to do a screen print of the entire workspace, but that could be a problem with personal info, so we went with a "screenprint" of the form only.

Comment: @MojoDK there is basically no way to do what you are asking, think about it, once the application throws an exception it's in a corrupt state and is effectively shutting down. It's not a very reliable solution. Like I said, logging the stack trace of the exception and implementing a proper logger framework is *far* more reliable.